# iMacros to JavaScript, Not Works After Converting

Tags: javascript, imacros

i don't many understan about iMacros and JavaScript.
i had a problem after converting .iim to .js
help me to correct this code become works and run as .js file, thanks guys.
Bellow my part of code, coverting using tools.

```
macro += "SET !DATASOURCE "must requirement.txt"" + "\n"; 

macro += "SET !VAR8 EVAL("var oala=\"{{!VAR1}}\"; var aha=oala.substring(oala.indexOf(\"{{!VAR9}}\")-6,oala.indexOf(\"{{!VAR9}}\")-2); aha")" + "\n"; 

macro += "SET !VAR5 EVAL("var oala=\"{{!VAR4}}\"; var adu=oala.substring(oala.indexOf(\"{{!VAR1}}\")-8,oala.indexOf(\"{{!VAR1}}\")-2); adu")" + "\n"; 

macro += "URL GOTO=javascript:((function(){if(window.content.document.getElementsByClassName('selectedtab')[0].textContent!="3%20Media"){window.content.document.getElementById('listingform').submit.click();}}))();" + "\n"; 

macro += "URL GOTO=http://myname.com/fp_fans" + "\n"; 

macro += "SET !FOLDER_DATASOURCE C:\all<SP>product\parfum" + "\n";

macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:form1 ATTR=NAME:anulah CONTENT=%{{!COL28}}" + "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using the [iMacros script code creator](https://sourceforge.net/projects/imacros-codegen/). Unfortunately this has since its release not been updated. The issue is, that it doesnt escape several characters, which need to be escaped in a string file in use to be used.

I would suggest you use [iMacros Java Script Converter](https://xs-sol.com/imacros-java-script-converter/) since this tool does the same but also [escapes special characters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html).